# How to execute a npm/yarn script when testing a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing a VSCode extension which I bundle with esbuild, as suggested [in VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension#using-esbuild). Following the docs, I added new script entries in my `package.json`, including:

```js
"esbuild": "yarn run esbuild-base -- --sourcemap"
```

Now I must run `yarn run esbuild`, then hit `f5` each time I want to test my extension. This is a source of confusion, because if I forget the first part, I'm going to test my old code.

To avoid this I wonder if it's possible to automatically run `yarn run esbuild` when I press f5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a task to perform the `yarn` call
- add this task as a `preLaunchTask` to your debug launch config

Or maybe you can setup an `npm`-watch script